# Spring-GraphQL: Refer to schema.graphqls definition located in separate JAR

Tags: spring-boot, graphql, spring-graphql

The Spring-GraphQL service I am working on requires a `schema.graphqls` file to be present at runtime. The [spring-graphql documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-graphql/docs/1.0.0-M2/reference/html/#boot-graphql-schema) describes a default location where the schema can be resolved:

> By default, GraphQL schema files are expected to be in
> `src/main/resources/graphql` and have the extension `".graphqls"`,
> `".graphql"`, `".gql"`, or `".gqls"`.

The schema I would like to use is located in a different jar on the classpath. The Spring documentation indicates that the property `spring.graphql.schema.locations` can be used to alter the location of the file:

> You can customize the schema locations to check as follows:
> `spring.graphql.schema.locations=classpath:graphql/`

I have tried several values (such as `classpath:**`) but I cannot seem to give the correct location. Would anyone know what value to use when the schema is located in a separate JAR?

I have verified the presence of the schema resource using `SomeClass.class.getResource("/schema.graphqls").toURI();`, which returned the schema URI:

```
jar:file:/home/{myname}/.m2/repository/com/organisation/some-external-lib/1.2.3/some-external-lib-1.2.3.jar!/schema.graphqls
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a [thread on github](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-graphql/issues/489) where a similar issue is discussed. I fixed my problem by using the following configuration:

```
spring.graphql.schema.locations=classpath*:/
```